# SQL inserting numerous columns for matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, multiple-columns

Is there any quick way I could transpose values in a row to column headers.. say I have row values `A`, `B`, `C` ... `Z` in a column called indx_nm. Is there a easy way to make column headers `A`, `B`, `C` ... `Z`  without having to manually populate this (I have 1000 distinct values that I meet to make a covariance matrix out of)

Answer (score 0):

You may use dynamic PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,indx_nm)
            FROM TableName c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from             (
                select indx_nm,
                Othercolumn
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Othercolumn)
                for indx_nm in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE @query

Comment: please post an example!

Comment: Sorry, i lost connection when i was ready to post an example. Now i am away from my pc, so i can only post some references.

Comment: This is what i assembled in my phone on top of my head, so give it a try and we'll see.

Comment: i keep getting a "incorrect syntax near '-' " on line 5 which will not go away.. weird it appears no matter how i change my code its always line 5 regardless of the code

Comment: You may have a problem on the indx_nm values. What kind of values do you have there?

Comment: You may also replace EXECUTE with PRINT, and see what sql is going to be executed. Then try that sql and see what errors you get.

Comment: and when i have `EXECUTE` it just prints `the name 'SELECT A, B, .... is not a valid identifier`

Comment: Can you post exactly the sql of the print? I am still on a phone so i cannot really test.

Comment: `DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);`

`SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,indx_nm) FROM' 'dWA_NSCC.[CORP\Eng].indx_nm c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')`
`SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + 'from'
 '(select indx_nm, Othercolumn from temp) x pivot ( max(Othercolumn) for indx_nm in (' + @cols + ') ) p' `

`EXECUTE @query`

`SELECT * FROM dWA_NSCC.[CORP\Eng].indx_nm
ORDER BY indx_nm`

Comment: Thanks but i meant the one exposed by the print.

Comment: `DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,indx_nm) FROM dWA_NSCC.[CORP\Eng].indx_nm c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + 'from
 (select indx_nm, Othercolumn from temp) x pivot ( max(Othercolumn) for indx_nm in (' + @cols + ') ) p' 

PRINT @query`
returns: `SELECT ABQI      ,ACNACTR   ,ACNITTR   ,ACNRET    ,ACNRMBTR  ,ACNSCT    ,AGIXLT    `(and on - all the indices i have listed in the rows)

Comment: I am afraid i will need a pc. I am really sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: every single one is distinct

Comment: Yes, but how many are there? EXECUTE has a limit of 4000 characters, so if the list is too big...